# Missing JavaFX application class com.MainApp

Tags: gradle, javafx, java-11, openjfx

I'm trying to migrate from java-1.8 to java-11..
I was facing the error "Missing JavaFX application class com.MainApp" and I looked for a solution online and found a couple of them:

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular

[Maven JavaFx project compiles but running from console give "Missing JavaFX application class" error msg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861520/maven-javafx-project-compiles-but-running-from-console-give-missing-javafx-appl)

The above approach is to "create a new main class and call the main method of a class which extends application"

However, I'm still facing below issues:

I am running it through the command line and using the below commands:

**1.Java -jar abc.jar**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
>           at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>           at com.amx.rms.transporter.tools.config.MainDivert.main(MainDivert.java:7)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>           ... 10 more

**2.java --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing -jar abc.jar**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/Context
>           at com.amx.rms.transporter.tools.config.MainDivert.main(MainDivert.java:7)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.Context
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>           ... 1 more

Below is my new main class:

```
public class MainDivert {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            MainApp.main(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach looks quite promising. You already managed to add the JavaFX modules. So that's working.
It seems, you have a couple of other libs you depend on, like logback. You'll have to add them to the classpath (or modulepath) as well.

Gradle can actually manage all the dependencies for you. You could start your app using `gradle run`. See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle

If you want to run the jar from the command line, you'll have to list all the dependencies in the classpath (module path) manually. This can be quite a pain.